# apache airflow 1.10.9 statsd enabled making scheduler crashed

Tags: airflow, statsd

my airflow running in CeleryExecutor mode + progresql 12, all things go well except when turning statsd on:

```
statsd_on = True
statsd_host = localhost
statsd_port = 8125
statsd_prefix = airflow
```

The schedulers can render jobs but jobs are not running, the scheduler log having below error:

```
[SQL: SELECT count(*) AS count_1 
FROM task_instance 
WHERE task_instance.pool = %(pool_1)s AND task_instance.state IN (%(state_1)s, %(state_2)s)]
[parameters: {'pool_1': 'default_pool', 'state_1': 'running', 'state_2': 'queued'}]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/4xp6)[0m
[31mTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1246, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 588, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
psycopg2.errors.ProtocolViolation: invalid frontend message type 97
server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/jobs/scheduler_job.py", line 1495, in _validate_and_run_task_instances
    self._process_and_execute_tasks(simple_dag_bag)

  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 588, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (psycopg2.errors.ProtocolViolation) invalid frontend message type 97
server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
```

If disable statsd, everything resume.  Is it a bug for airflow? any advise to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same error, and after a few tests, i can get statsd metrics working. Typically, you will see the error if the following conditions are met.

- Statsd enabled set to True
- SqlAlchemy connection pool set to True
- Scheduler syserr log enabled (by redirect the err log to a file where you can see this error)

In my case, even though the scheduler kept throwing the error logs, statsd metrics were still delivered, and tasks were also scheduled as they should. I dont know how to measure the impact, i also dont want to sacrifice sql_alchemy connection pool, so I leave statsd turned off.

(*I guess other people not seeing the error because they are missing the 3rd one above*)